# "Unable to open the Security Manager Database" Error while installing a windows service using service installer on Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services

I am on win 7 and trying to install a .NET windows service using the service installer. And get the error as shown in the pic. I thought Its becuase I was not admin on that machine and got that error. but then I used an admin account and got the same error. Any idea what could be the reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your process elevated. Right click -> Run as administrator.

If you suspect the problem in the installer, it is easy to install service from command line. The command is

```
sc create <MyServiceName> binPath= <PathToServiceExe>
```

You will need to execute this command from elevated cmd window.

Comment: "Run your process elevated. Right click -> Run as administrator." is the way to go. Thanks!